# Custom Designer Property Categories in Sitefinity

Tags: c#, properties, widget, categories, sitefinity

I am trying to categorize custom designer properties.

I followed simple coding instructions from this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M65LWLkoaGo)

However, none of the categories are showing in my designer on the backend.

Here is the code for some of the properties I am trying to categorize:

```
    [Category("Setup")]
    public int SetupId { get; set; }
    [Category("Color")]
    public string ColorDesc { get; set; }
    [Category("Color")]
    public string ColorLink { get; set; }
    [Category("Shapes & Sizes")]
    public string ShapeDesc { get; set; }
    [Category("Shapes & Sizes")]
    public string ShapeLink { get; set; }
```

Wondering if there is any other code I need to add to implement these categories into my custom designer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in designer should show the categories, but only after you click on the "Categorized" button, by default the Alphabetically button is selected and it does not show the categories.

It is a behaviour inherited from Visual Studio properties window.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to programmatically disable the Alphabetical button?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, sorry.